# Django Custom Field with Fernet Cannot Decrypt

Tags: django, postgresql, cryptography, fernet

This is my custom field that I call in a model. Migrations succeed and I'm able to insert an encrypted value into the data table. However, it will not decrypt.

Here's the custom field class:

```
class SecureString(CharField):
    """Custom Encrypted Field"""

    #kdf = X963KDF(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                    # length=32,
                     #sharedinfo=None,
                    # backend=default_backend())

    key = bytes(settings.FERNET_KEY,'utf-8')
    f = Fernet(key)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):

        return self.f.decrypt(str.encode(value))

    def get_prep_value(self, value):

        return self.f.encrypt(bytes(value, 'utf-8'))
```

And here is the error when trying to retrieve values from the data table:

```
File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:706, in PlainTextFormatter.__call__(self, obj)
    699 stream = StringIO()
    700 printer = pretty.RepresentationPrinter(stream, self.verbose,
    701     self.max_width, self.newline,
    702     max_seq_length=self.max_seq_length,
    703     singleton_pprinters=self.singleton_printers,
    704     type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    705     deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 706 printer.pretty(obj)
    707 printer.flush()
    708 return stream.getvalue()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py:410, in RepresentationPrinter.pretty(self, obj)
    407                         return meth(obj, self, cycle)
    408                 if cls is not object \
    409                         and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 410                     return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    412     return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    413 finally:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py:778, in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    776 """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    777 # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 778 output = repr(obj)
    779 lines = output.splitlines()
    780 with p.group():

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:370, in QuerySet.__repr__(self)
    369 def __repr__(self):
--> 370     data = list(self[: REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
    371     if len(data) > REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE:
    372         data[-1] = "...(remaining elements truncated)..."

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:376, in QuerySet.__len__(self)
    375 def __len__(self):
--> 376     self._fetch_all()
    377     return len(self._result_cache)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:1867, in QuerySet._fetch_all(self)
   1865 def _fetch_all(self):
   1866     if self._result_cache is None:
-> 1867         self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
   1868     if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
   1869         self._prefetch_related_objects()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:204, in ValuesIterable.__iter__(self)
    198 names = [
    199     *query.extra_select,
    200     *query.values_select,
    201     *query.annotation_select,
    202 ]
    203 indexes = range(len(names))
--> 204 for row in compiler.results_iter(
    205     chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size
    206 ):
    207     yield {names[i]: row[i] for i in indexes}

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1336, in SQLCompiler.apply_converters(self, rows, converters)
   1334     value = row[pos]
   1335     for converter in convs:
-> 1336         value = converter(value, expression, connection)
   1337     row[pos] = value
   1338 yield row

File /code/server/identity/model_mixins.py:61, in SecureString.from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection)
     59 key = bytes(settings.FERNET_KEY, 'utf-8')
     60 f = Fernet(key)
---> 61 return f.decrypt(str.encode(value))

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py:86, in Fernet.decrypt(self, token, ttl)
     83 def decrypt(
     84     self, token: typing.Union[bytes, str], ttl: typing.Optional[int] = None
     85 ) -> bytes:
---> 86     timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
     87     if ttl is None:
     88         time_info = None

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py:119, in Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
    117     data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(token)
    118 except (TypeError, binascii.Error):
--> 119     raise InvalidToken
    121 if not data or data[0] != 0x80:
    122     raise InvalidToken

InvalidToken:
```

Been scratching my head at this for hours. Works perfectly fine in a standalone python script. Is django doing something to the fernet key upon decrypting I'm unaware of?

Database is Postgres 12.4

### EDIT:

The database value appears as this: `\x674141414141426b384d34596e535f6d6a6b3173556b5344455f57585a58326851374b35576c56536938676d3358556165515a767a677a754f6c4b7a646c613276397644455874675276795971724b794e616744596f6d516d78694a5167335334654d526b784d495156566d7344575242776e3639487143515044334f676e65334e524268624a5742786f544258336f435930675f6c646c6c524a44714b56466d4f7836575f5f6c5772556e4a6d4f3372325372636b33536a6a346d7a536c56415635386f474c44596d646962774c42384e4e4d645657464a3743567a55597854673d3d`

while the encrypted value with a standalone encryption with fernet shows this (same key used):
`gAAAAABk8M1BhMeOF10wcEZ7U6zb_vQpaQ8zHxlDuGLyFCA6JQu0NSYfshulqorntWQS4OF7PAyyQ7BCJZ2r0QNt7e8FBZbjTQ==`

Comment: I wanted to add to the above error I'm getting since it definitely helps with Diagnosing. Its an error earlier on that says `Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (201) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4` So is this an issue when it's being encrypted rather than decrypted?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package that I have used successfully for encrypted fields. `django-encrypted-model-fields`

My model looks like this:

```html
from django.db import models
from encrypted_model_fields.fields import EncryptedCharField


class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = EncryptedCharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And add in `settings.py`

INSTALLED_APPS = [
....
'encrypted_model_fields',

I set the encryption key with the environment variable `FIELD_ENCRYPTION_KEY`

I do not need to do anything else.

Comment: In postgres, if you write a query to decrypt the results, are you able to do so with the decrypt function? I'm interested in AES encrpytion provided by my custom class above for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

I know not the most secure, but entire database is encrypted at rest as is. This is to obfuscate data from other employees at the company. I know CBC is a better AES mode.

Using AES encryption, I can write encrypted values and read them from Django this way. I can also decrypt with pgcrypto extension in postgres with a sql query. Still working on an issue with that which will be posted as another question.

```
class EncryptField(models.BinaryField):
description = "Encrypted column"

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['max_length'] = 255
    kwargs['blank'] = True
    kwargs['null'] = True
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def deconstruct(self):
    name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
    del kwargs["max_length"]
    del kwargs["blank"]
    del kwargs["null"]
    return name, path, args, kwargs

def get_prep_value(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return value
    enc_secret = AES.new(settings.AES_KEY.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_ECB)
    cipher_text = base64.b64encode(enc_secret.encrypt(pad(value.encode('utf-8'), AES.block_size)))
    return cipher_text

def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
    if value is None:
        return value
    raw = base64.b64decode(value)
    dec_secret = AES.new(settings.AES_KEY.encode('utf-8'),AES.MODE_ECB)
    clear_val = unpad(dec_secret.decrypt(raw), AES.block_size)
    return clear_val

def to_python(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, Identity):
        return value
    if value is None:
        return value
    dec_secret = AES.new(settings.AES_KEY.encode('utf-8'),AES.MODE_ECB)
    clear_val = unpad(dec_secret.decrypt(value), AES.block_size)
    return clear_val
```